# How update DB Value with NULL using Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to update the DB value to NULL using Properties, but the NULL values are not updated.
  The following is the code snippet

```
def a = Docs.findById(1)
a.properties = b
```

b has the following values

```
[name:abc, level:null]
```

Data appears not to be saving into the DB. How can I save the data?

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: have you called `a.save()`?

Comment: It is Dirty Saving, so i didn't call a.save()

Comment: what is `level`?  and what does `a.validate()` say after you have changed `level`?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?  Does level allow nulls?

Comment: is `level` a `long` or `Long` ?